# Convert/Serialize kendo grid filters passed as string inside controller to readable structure

Tags: serialization, filter, kendo-ui

I want to create a faceted search for a KendoUI grid. 
That i want to do is, pass a kendo filter to controller, translate this filters into sql query and return grouped data.

My controller

```
public List<facetSearchOptionsModel> optionsCount(string filter)
    { ... }
```

In client i call this

```
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:17446/api/Facet/optionsCount',
                params: {
                    filter: filt
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            }, function errorCallback(response) { });
            return deferred.promise;
```

The KendoUI(javascript) filter object, can have this structure

```
{
logic: "and",
filters: [
   {
     logic: "or",
     filters: [
         { field: "Level", operator: "eq", value: 'INFO' },
     ]
  },
  {
     logic: "or",
     filters: [
         { field: "Logger", operator: "eq", value: 'AgentSync' },
     ]
  },
  {field:"Message",operator:"contains",value:"fgdgfdgfd"}
]}
```

When i call this in client i get that

for example: `"{\"logic\":\"and\",\"filters\":[{\"logic\":\"or\",\"filters\":[{\"field\":\"Level\",\"operator\":\"eq\",\"value\":\"INFO\"}]},{\"logic\":\"or\",\"filters\":[{\"field\":\"Logger\",\"operator\":\"eq\",\"value\":\"AgentSync\"}]},{\"field\":\"Message\",\"operator\":\"contains\",\"value\":\"fgdgfdgfd\"}]}"`

How can deserialize this string into a object so i can do for-loop?
Or how can translate this string into a sql query?

I repeat my self, how can convert a kendo datasource filter object from string to readable structure in client so i can take the values and create an sql query?

Comment: Any news on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a specific ViewModel for that, e.g.:

```
public class KendoFilterViewModel 
{
    public string logic { get; set; 

    public string field { get; set; }

    public string operator { get; set; }

    public string value { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<KendoFilterViewModel> filters { get; set; }
}
```

Then your controller signature:

```
public List<facetSearchOptionsModel> optionsCount(KendoFilterViewModel filter)
```

Comment: Thank you for solution. This worked for me. I was getting error for operator string so I have added JsonProperty as per below : https://gist.github.com/QiMata/8d22ed102ea119664d7aec6e1b913f45